# Backlight slider no longer works in Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, acpi, asus, backlight

I'm running Linux Mint 18 Cinnamon on my Asus X555LA, which also has Windows 10 installed on another partition (the backlight works perfectly in Windows).

However in Linux Mint: there's already an issue with Fn+F5/F6 not changing the backlight intensity. The various fixes I've tried (**but haven't worked**) include:

- adding a `20-intel.conf` file into the `/usr/share/X11` folder.
- added `acpi_osi=` to the `/etc/default/grub`
- Running `acpi_listen` and pressing Fn+F5/F6 shows no output.
- Installing `xbacklight` and running `xbacklight -set $percentage`

Until about two days ago I could skirt this issue by using the brightness slider in the UI, however even this no longer works and the screen brightness is stuck at 100%.

I am at a loss and no longer know what to do.

Comment: useful info would be dmeg output, dsdt dump, also what dirs exist in "/sys/class/backlight/" currently?

Answer (score 0):

```
lsmod | grep video
```

(*video* is the kernel driver that handles *acpi* calls for brightness)

You can check if *"/sys/class/backlight/acpi_video0"* exists, and you can use;

```
acpi_listen
```

...to check for the acpi event.

Essentially the firmware triggers one of the Q functions which triggers a notify to the monitor with either 0x87 or 0x86, when this is received the brightness can be changed.

If for whatever reason the DSDT tables doesn't have certain methods like _DOD then kernel *acpi* wont recognize the definition of a monitor.

Regardless, you can boot your kernel with `acpi_backlight=video` to force *video.ko* to control the backlight (this will use *acpi* based values defined in BCL).

When you use vendor it'll use vendor specific *acpi* or rely simply on the pci device.

Regardless of *acpi* you can always change your brightness via pci bypassing *acpi*.

To do this check out */sys/class/backlight/* for a dir with the name *amd* or *intel*.

You can echo to the brightness file, this won't use the brightness levels defined in the DSDT tables so you actually get a larger variety of brightness levels.

PS... the only forced detections for Asus laptops are to force vendor.

These laptops are;

- Asus UL30VT
- Asus UL30A

There is no reference for *"X555LA"*, so I'd try `acpi_backlight=video` before `acpi_backlight=vendor`.

Comment: No offence, but this answer just reads like a ramble. Any chance of clarifying what you mean, please?

Comment: If you try adding "acpi_backlight=video", in grub or whatever boot loader you have, then test the buttons and also acpi_listen again. if this does not solve your problem, i'll update the post.